# JBoss 6: i can't deploy a ejb (jar) project on my server

Tags: java, maven, classpath, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

i have tow projects :
1=> MyApplication (WAR) where i use some EJB by Injecting them (@EJB)
2=> MyEJBProject where i have all my Interfaces and Implimentations annoted by @Statless and @local

I work with jboss EAP6.

When i try to clean and install the EJBProject first , it works good but when i wanna put it on the server (deployement folder ) it gives me the following errors :

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."org-services-abk.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."org-services-abk.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: N'a pas pu traiter la phase POST_MODULE de deployment "org-services-abk.jar"
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Erreur d'obtention d'informations réflectives pour class eu.org.dataservice.abk.action.impl.GroupVersionHome pour le ClassLoader (Chargeur de classe) ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.org-services-abk.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
      at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/envers/exception/RevisionDoesNotExistException
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.envers.exception.RevisionDoesNotExistException from [Module "deployment.org-services-abk.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
... 15 more
```

Comment: Any one to give me a response !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest-Version: 1.0
...
Dependencies: org.hibernate, org.hibernate.envers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your META-INF/MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
...
Dependencies: org.hibernate, org.hibernate.envers
```

Also checked to see the dependence on your project with envers, must be Hibernate Envers **4.2.7.SP1.Final** for JBoss EAP 6.2

See the docs: [JPA Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-NativeHibernateuse)

Comment: sorry i tested your solution and i reboot the server , i saw that the app service was deployed , so when i reboot the server all applica in the deploy folder come deployed but when i copy the jar from target folder to deploy folder it gives me the errors written before